# Accordion in jQuery ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to Convert one header and one content panel into an accordion.

```
<div id="accordion-two">
    <h3>Header</h3>
    <div>Content panel</div>
</div>
```

this is jQuery code

```
$('#accordion-two').accordion({
    header: 'h3',
    event: 'click',
    animated: 'swing',
    duration: 800, 
    active: false
});
```

my question is I need to apply click event to header to open the content panel and to collapse the content panel..

thank you..

Comment: question doesn't make sense... an accordion already toggles content. If it isn't doing that.. chances are you have script errors beig thrown...look in browser console

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GWhaz/2/

Comment: working only one time. I need to collapse content again when click header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple set the [collapsable](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible) attribute.

```
$('#accordion-two').accordion(
    {
    header: 'h3', 
    event: 'click',  
    animated: 'swing', 
    duration: 800, 
    active: false,  
    collapsible: true 
    }
);​
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference jQuery UI in your code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also as mentioned in the other answer by default there should always be an expanded panel so if you have only one panel it cannot be collapsed unless you toggle the `collapsible` option. `collapsible: true`